# MS Excel - Converting Text to Date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to convert the field below to a date field in the for mm/dd/yyyy.

17-JAN-18 10.54.53.000000000 AM

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data in cell A1, you can use the formular `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,9))`.

You'll probably have to format it manually as a date cell:

1. Right-click on the cells you want to format as described
2. **Format Cells ...**
3. Select **Date** from Categories
4. Select the format you would like to apply

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I would like to suggest you two methods to Convert the Value, into the mm/dd/yyyy format.

**Method 1 Cell Format:**

- Select the Cell.
- Click Home Tab.
- Find & Hit the Number Command.
- Under Number category find Custom.
- Apply mm/dd/yyyy.
- Finish with Ok.

**Method 2 use Text Function.**

```
=MONTH(A2) & "/" & DAY(A2) & "/" & YEAR(A2)
```

**NB:** I've assumed the Value is in Cell A2, change the Cell address in the Formula as per the position.

*I do hope this help you.*